# Change code based on existing attribute?

Tags: c#, shared-libraries, aop, postsharp

I'm writing a library which is shared between .net and silverlight.  I have several places where I am doing this, to satisfy the silverlight deserialization (which can't access private members):

```
    [DataMember (IsRequired = true)]
    public Object MyProperty { get; 
#if SILVERLIGHT
        internal    
#else
        private 
#endif
         set; }
```

I know the rules for this, which are that if the setter is private and SILVERLIGHT is defined then the setter should be internal.

Could I use an aspect oriented framework like postsharp to help me reduce this code so that I don't need to specify anything and it will inspect the property, if it has the DataMember attribute and the setter is private, then make the setter internal instead?

Or is there some other technique I could use for this?

**EDIT**

There seems to be some confusion.  My goal is to **avoid having the compiler directives at all**, but to still have code which is generated with a private member in .net and with a member that can be set by the `DataContractDeserializer` in Silverlight, which can't access private members.  If possible I'd like to automatically modify the property in a silverlight build so it is internal, whilst not having anything other than the `DataMember` attribute in the source.

Ideally I see the solution being something like:

- Write an aspect which checks every property or field.
- If the property/field has the `[DataMember]` attribute then

  - If the silverlight compiler directive exists then

    - if the setter is private make it internal (for properties) or if it is declared as private make it internal (for fields)

but I'm not sure which bits of that it would be possible to do using a tool like post sharp.

Comment: Woudlnt doing this cause potential issues? Are these members not accessed outside of the class? Internal = public to assembly while private means only class has access.

Comment: @DustinDavis as the *same* code is compiled by both .net and silverlight anywhere that were to use the internal variable would not compile in the .net build, as in that build it is private.  A dev would have to use the property inside a `#if SILVERLIGHT` compiler directive for it not to cause a problem, which they could do, but is unlikely

Comment: Lots of people try to do this and I don't know why. Just use different assemblies using shared code (as much as possible anyway). You're writing code in a horrible way.

Comment: What type of serialization are you trying to do? PostSharp might be able to help you there. I wrote a property injection aspect that can be applied to any property, private or not. Maybe that is how you need to go

Comment: @Titan2782 I'm not sure I know what you mean by 'Just use different assemblies using shared code'.  Isn't this exactly what I'm trying to do?

Comment: yes, but you're taking the wrong approach. Your apps will be littered with directives making it very hard to read and debug. Abstract common code and then implement framework specific code. What are you trying to achieve? You can't share your library this way it has to be compiled each time. these are 'compiler' directives that tell the compiler what to do. no affect at runtime.

Comment: @Dustin is there an example of the property injection aspect anywhere?

Comment: @Titan, using this approach I can have WCF deserialize my messages into strongly typed objects with behaviour on the silverlight client.  the silverlight version of my libraries are built from the same code that is used on the server and so will provide the same functionality.  The biggest issue with this is that the silverlight runtime does not have the trust environment to access private members and so the members have to be internal.  Finding a solution to automating the change from private to internal so that the WCF messages can be correctly deserialized into library objects... ctd

Comment: without using the #if directives will mean that I don't need to litter my code with them, which I don't want.

Comment: @Sam you need to use DTO's so you dont have to have private/internal members. DTO's are lightweight versions of your data and always (usually) use public properties. don't pass around your models or business objects. See my answer below for example of property injection

Comment: @Dustin and we should then create business objects again from the DTO's on the client?  We are back and forthing with this discussion a bit at the moment and are unsure about the best way forward...

Comment: always use DTOs to transfer data/objects then do with them what you need. If that requires building business objects then so be it. You then decouple your service from your client which is what you want. Your service and client don't need to know anything about each other except the common interface (using DTOs) which have only the exact required members and nothing more.

Comment: @Dustin, we are considering using entity framework self tracking entities which would not be compatible with services implemented using DTOs I don't think.  Interoperability is a secondary concern for us.  Thanks for the input though, it is much appreciated

Comment: Since @DustinDavis did answer your question about PostSharp, don't forget to mark it as the answer.

Comment: thanks Titan, but I'll wait a while to see if others have any take on it before marking it as the accepted answer, if that's ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers either attack the merit of the problem or present alternative approaches that do not directly answer the question.  The question was whether there was a way to change the visibility of the setter for a property with a DataMember attribute after it is compiled, to support two versions (.NET and Silverlight).

I suspect the PostSharp SDK would support this.  However, this is a problem I had to solve while developing [Afterthought](https://github.com/vc3/Afterthought), as I needed to change the visibility of anonymous static delegates generated by the C# compiler (normally private until I made them internal).  Afterthought itself does not currently support your scenario directly, but it leverages the open source [Microsoft CCI](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/) libraries, which do.  The [IL Mutator](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/61787#559891) example shows how to use the CCI libraries to load a compiled assembly and modify it by creating a mutable copy.  The example is actually much more complex than your scenario, as you will not be modifying IL, just the visibility of a setter.

This is an example of changing the visibility of a method from within a mutator in CCI:

```
public override MethodDefinition Mutate(MethodDefinition methodDef)     
{
    // Automatically make all private static methods to have internal scope
    if (methodDef.IsStatic && methodDef.Visibility == TypeMemberVisibility.Private)
        methodDef.Visibility = TypeMemberVisibility.Assembly;
```

This is a slightly simplified [excerpt](https://github.com/vc3/Afterthought/blob/master/Afterthought.Amender/AssemblyAmender.cs#L806) from the Afterthought amender.  There are also examples in the same class for how to determine if a method is a setter (starts with set_, HideBySig, etc).  You would just need to create a mutator, override the method in this example, verify that the method is a property setter with a DataMember attribute on the containing property definition, and change the visibility.

Comment: Thanks.  This directly addresses my question and provides a way to do exactly what I want.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is NO. PostSharp is a Post-Compile framework so you cannot use your compiler directives (as you're trying to do in your question). You can use PostSharp to

1. Introduce properties into the class with the accessors desired (which doesn't give you access at design time) Directives can be applied to the aspect at design time to determine which property to inject though
2. Or use reflection to change the accessor (I dont think you can do that)

An alternative is to use T4 templates to generate these classes for you

Edit: Example of property injection

```
[Serializable]
    [MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Class, Inheritance = MulticastInheritance.Strict)]
    public class PropInj : InstanceLevelAspect
    {
#if SILVERLIGHT
        [IntroduceMember(OverrideAction = MemberOverrideAction.Ignore, IsVirtual=true, Visibility=Visibility.FamilyAndAssembly)]
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }
#else
        [IntroduceMember(OverrideAction = MemberOverrideAction.Ignore, IsVirtual = true, Visibility = Visibility.Private)]
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }
#endif
    }

    [PropInj]
    public class test
    {
        //public int MyProperty { get; set; }

        public test()
        {

        }

    }
```

but really you need to rethink your design.

Comment: No, I think you misunderstood.  I want to **get rid of the compiler directives**.  I want to use something like post sharp to generate the property differently for silverlight than for .net, so that these copmpiler directives do not litter the code.

Comment: from the answer it sounds like I might be able introduce a different set accessor based on compiler directives applied to the aspect, which would then enable me to put the compiler directive in a single place and have all my [DataMember] properties/fields be altered depending on the directive